# Bash script to extract information from a file

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I need to extract information from a joomla configuration file using bash script. 
**configuration.php**

```
var $host = 'localhost';
var $user = 'root';
var $db = 'mydb';
```

I need to get the value of variable $db. Please help.

Comment: What efforts did you make yourself? Post it along with the question, even though they are trivial

Comment: Tried this  echo $str | cut -d "$db = ' " -f2 | cut -d " ' " -f1

Comment: Your attempts suggest using a string, but in the question it says a php file. Clarify it exactly and update the question accordingly

Comment: That's some pretty old-fashioned PHP you've got there if you're using `var`...

Comment: sed -r -n '/\$db/{s@.*=[[:space:]]*'\''([^'\'']*)'\''.*@\1@g;p}' configuration.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep "\$db"  configuration.php | sed 's/var $db = //' | tr -d "';"
```

will return the value of the variable

Based on the comment:

Given the `configuration.php`:

```
var $host = 'localhost';
var $user = 'root';
var $db = 'mydb';
var $dbuser = 'user'
```

The following:

```
grep "\$db "  configuration.php | sed 's/var $db = //' | tr -d "';"
```

will return only the variable in `$db`, ignoring the variable `$dbuser`, i.e. output:

```
mydb
```

Comment: Thanks, will it return just the string without quotes?

Comment: @Ash See edit, pipe it with `tr`

Comment: @Ash Did it work for you? :)

Comment: Thanks, it works. but how to do this by ignoring whitespaces between $db and =?

Comment: Because I have multiple lines that matches $db keyword like $dbuser = 'user'; etc.

Comment: @Ash If you want to ignore the variable inside `$dbuser` , and just return the variable inside `$db`, see the edited answer: you just need a space in the `grep` command: `grep "\$db "` instead of `grep "\$db"`

Comment: thanks all fine now

Answer (score 0):

you can try to do something like this:

```
$( cat test.txt | sed 's/var \$/export joomla_/g' | sed 's/ = /=/g' | sed 's/;//g' | sed "s/'//g" )

echo $joomla_host $joomla_user $joomla_db
```

but it's not very clear what you want to achieve